# Match specific string + any float number in python

Tags: python, 3d

I am writing a script for Luxology modo (3D and VFX application), which is using python as scripting language. Somewhere in my script i am reading text file outputted from other app, and creating materials and image maps from the lines of this text file. one of the things i am doing there is creating a dictionary of the channel names from this text file, and mapping each channel name to the modo's internal channel name, so modo could understand what to do with this channels. This is a snippet that doing it:

```
# this is a dictionary of the channel names in the textures.txt file
# mapped to modo's internal channel names
channels = {'color':'diffColor', 'specular':'specAmount', 'normalmap':'normal'}
for channel in channels:
    if channel in materials[mat].keys():
============AND SO ON==============
```

Everything works as expected, but there is one more channel - displacement. And the problem is that it's not just a string as other channels, but a string followed by a float number, which is a scale factor for displacement, like this:
displacement 19.378531

For now i want just to create displacement image map in modo, as i am already doing with other maps (color, normals, specular), without using this 'scale factor' number in any way. It seems easy enough, and i have tried to use Regular Expression to match string "displacement" followed by random float number, but it does not works (or, i do not use it properly)!

How can i tell python to do instead of

```
channels = {'color':'diffColor', 'specular':'specAmount', 'normalmap':'normal', 'displacement':'displace'}
```

to do this:

```
channels = {'color':'diffColor', 'specular':'specAmount', 'normalmap':'normal', 'displacement' + 'ANY_FLOAT_NUMBER':'displace'}
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you want to do exactly, but here's the regex to match "displacement<space><any float>": `displacement\s[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+`

Comment: +1 for a question related to shader programming. Would love to see more of that on SO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your [pastebin](http://vfxdomain.pastebin.com/MSVhsCbD), I believe this should work for you:

```
# ...
infile.close()

channels = {'color':'diffColor', 'specular':'specAmount', 'normalmap':'normal'}
re_dis = re.compile(r'displacement\s[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+')

for material, values in materials.items():
    lx.eval('select.item {Matr: %s} set textureLayer' % material)
    uvmap = materials[material]['uvmap']
    for v in values:
        m = re_dis.match(v)
        if m or v in channels.keys():
            lx.eval('shader.create constant')
            lx.eval('item.setType imageMap textureLayer')
            imagepath = materials[material][v]
            imagename = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(imagepath))[0]
            lx.eval('clip.addStill {%s}' % imagepath)
            lx.eval('texture.setIMap {%s}' % imagename)
            if m:
                # we can't auto map to the channels dict
                lx.eval('shader.setEffect %s' % 'displace')
            else:
                lx.eval('shader.setEffect %s' % channels[v])
```

Also don't forget to add `import re` to the top of your script.

Comment: Thanks a lot offsound, it's works, but there is a problem of duplicates, your code creates all needed maps, but duplicates it a few times. I'll see if i can fix it, i should learn your snippet more in depth. For now this is what i did, i am running this func before creating the dictionary from textures.txt, so it just replaces 'displacement + float' with 'displacement', and then i can map displacement to displace effect as i do with other channels: channels = {'color':'diffColor', 'specular':'specAmount', 'normalmap':'normal', 'displacement':'displace'} 
http://vfxdomain.pastebin.com/V0SRRPR4

Comment: Ops, excuse me offsound, i was wrong and duplicates was not because of your code, it's because i have not removed some code that your snippet should replace. I have fixed it and it works perfectly now, thanks a lot! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using standard string methods to strip the coefficient from the string if it begins with 'displacement':

```
for material in materials[mat].keys():
    if material.startswith('displacement'):
        # coefficient = float(material.split('displacement')[1])
        material = material.rstrip('0123456789.')
    if material in channels:
        channelName = channels[material]
        ...
```

I've added commented-out instruction that you can uncomment if you later decide you want the coefficient (might be important if you start getting displacement artefacts!).

---

Edit after reading comments and full code.

You can't have anything programmatic or varying in a dictionary key. But if you want to keep the pattern you've already got, the simplest solution would be to ignore my suggestion above and just remove the floats at the end before you start searching with a quick loop like this:

```
for channel in channels:
    for key in materials[mat].keys():
        if "." in key:
            materials[mat][key.rstrip("0123456789.")] = materials[mat].pop(key)
    if channel in materials[mat].keys():
```

Comment: Thanks Ian, it looks like a solution for my problem. I am not sure though how to use it, let me show you the whole snippet: http://vfxdomain.pastebin.com/MSVhsCbD (How i can use your code here? Thanks in advance and sorry for lame questions)

Comment: What i am trying to achive is to add 'displacement' + any_float:'displace' to this: channels = {'color':'diffColor', 'specular':'specAmount', 'normalmap':'normal'}  BTW, the textures.txt file looks like this: http://vfxdomain.pastebin.com/Ejyh0YKw

Comment: Thanks Ian! I have not succeeded in using your code, but it's probably because of my lack of python knowledge (i am very fresh python user and coder in general). Where in my code i should place your snippet? It should replace something in my code?

Comment: The first and last lines of my second example are from the code in your question. Just add what's between them to your code without changing anything else.

Comment: And for a detailed overview of how to use `dict` objects and their methods, check out the mapping section of the built-in types page from the python docs: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict

Comment: Thanks Ian, i did it, but it does not worked for me, displacement map have not been created for some reason... Here is my code with yours as is: http://vfxdomain.pastebin.com/8Zjzj3aU

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure I understand the question, but I think you just have to do something a bit less efficient:

```
for material in materials:
    if material in channels:
        ...
    if 'displacement' in material:
        ...
```